# How to make AdView "occupy" space even while requesting an ad? (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, admob, banner-ads, adview

I'm using Google AdMob Ads SDK 4.0.4 for Android

By default, The AdView will have no size until the ad is loaded. Which could cause problem if you have buttons above or below the ad.

User could accidentally click on the ad if the ad returned at the exact moment they are about to click a button.

In old admob SDK I solved this by using setGoneWithoutAd(false). This way, the space will be preserved even when the ad is not returned yet.

In the new SDK (Google Admob Ads SDK 4.0.4) I manage to do the same by 
using this quick fix: reserve the space by putting ad in some layout that 
has width="320dp" and height="50dp"

```
<LinearLayout 
                        android:layout_width="320dp" 
                        android:layout_height="50dp" > 
                  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adview" 
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                         ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx" 
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"/> 
</LinearLayout>
```

It works but I'm not sure if this is a proper method.(Will I run into the famous "Not enough space to show ad!" issue? )

To sum up the question: How to(properly) make AdView "occupy" space even while requesting an ad?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: would you mark my answer as accepted if you think it's correct?

Answer (score 6):

First you have to decide the ad size that you want. There are a couple of pre-defined ones.

The easiest to work with is **SMART_BANNER**, it will adapt it's width to match the current screen width,
and it's height will be 32, 50 or 90 dp for screen heights <=400, (>400 && <=720) or  >720 dp respectively.

Once you know the type of banner you will request, you declare it on ***adSize*** property and reserve the space for this using ***layout_width*** and ***layout_height*** properties.

For example for an SMART_BANNER you can do something like this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/ad_banner_height"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxx"/>
```

And you will set ad_banner_height to the following values:

```
values/dimens/ad_banner_height --> 32dp
values-h400dp/dimens/ad_banner_height --> 50dp
values-h720dp/dimens/ad_banner_height --> 90dp
```

For other banner sizes, check: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner#banner_sizes

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried:

```
 <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adview" 
                     android:layout_width="320dip" 
                     android:layout_height="50dip" 
                     ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxx" 
                     ads:adSize="BANNER"/>
```

I use AdWhirl to serve my ads for me and the way I have it is with a fixed view similar to this with fixed dimensions. Looks like you have it set to wrap content making the view disappear when nothing's there. Try it out and let me know how it works out.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that didn't involve hard coding the size in to the layout :-(

Answer (score 0):

In my Banner design:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

If it is not premium mode I call this method

```
private void showBanner(){
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                mAdView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError);
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

first I show the banner occupying 60dp assigned in design, I have added a listener so that the space is hidden if the banner cannot be loaded, but if the banner is loaded it assigns in height and width WRAP_CONTENT and shows it